# Laravel Composer package include - QueryPath - How to use it correctly with the framework

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, querypath

When adding the package QueryPath ( https://github.com/technosophos/querypath/ ) via Composer to Laravel, how do I use it correctly?

It has no namespace, and I can't use it out of the box.

**Edit:**

**If you add that in your composer.json file, everything works out of the box:**

```
  "files": [
    "vendor/querypath/querypath/src/QueryPath.php"
  ]
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't use it out of the box? A class doesn't need to be namespaced to be able to use it (with or without Laravel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this package is not following the PSR-0 standard:

- Each namespace must have a top-level namespace ("Vendor Name").

Loading the `QueryPath` in your `composer.json` class might solve the problem temporarily.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        ...
    },
    "files": ["vendor/technosophos/querypath/src/QueryPath.php"]
},
```